# I want to show a date from parameter in reports output

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I want to display date parameter, in a standard report.
I am trying like this :
I have added a formula column like below:'

```
function P_DATEFormula return Date is
begin
  return to_date(:P_HIST_DATE ,'DD-MM-YYYY');
end;
```

This works in other reports but here does not appear in output.

Comment: it's not clear from where you cannot display ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have an oracle reports format file (.rdf) 
I create a formula column in rdf but formula column does not appear in output. 

I have been doing this in other reports but here somehow I cannot

Comment: Didn't you add a field on `the Layout Editor` and set source as `P_DATEFormula` with `DD-MM-RRRR` for `Format Mask` from `the Property Inspector` ?

Answer (score 1):

I must say that you are using a different function.

To display the date in the specified format in reports, You must use `TO_CHAR` function.

`TO_DATE` function just converts string to date and `TO_CHAR` converts it into the date to the specified string.

Date: By default, is displayed in the format specified in **NLS parameter**. If you want the date in some other format in reports `TO_CHAR` is the best option.

Like:

```
Select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyyy') from dual;
```

[Demo DB Fiddle for date formats](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cffee24b7bba1a6b843ebe58edbdcd26)

Cheers!!

Comment: @tajesh 
My issue is not format, 
It can be edited later too , 
My concern is to first have date displayed.